# How to know a group of dates are daily, weekly or monthly in Pandas Python?

Tags: python, date

I have a dataframe in Pandas with the date as index. "YYYY-MM-DD" format.
I have a lot of rows in this dataframe which means a lot of date indexes.

For all of these dates, most of them are daily continuous, some of them are weekly dates, some are yearly.

Example:

```
2015-01-05,
2015-01-06,
2015-01-07,
2015-01-08,
2015-01-09,
2015-01-16,
2015-01-23,
2015-01-30,
2015-02-28,
2015-03-30
```

So Some of them are daily dates and maybe then follow by several monthly dates or weekly dates, yearly dates.

**So how can I know in which dates duration, it is daily, weekly, monthly and yearly?**

Remark: the daily one only have working day dates (Monday - Friday). 
For Weekly dates, the Friday dates will be displayed.
For Monthly/Quarterly/Yearly dates, the last day of this month/quarter/year will be displayed.

Comment: Is my solution helpful?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
freq = pd.infer_freq(dataframe['Date'])
```

This freq will return the frequency of the dates. Please have a read for the "infer_freq" docs.